# Calling modal on a list of products opens the modal for all of them instead of just the one being clciked

Tags: react-native, react-modal

I am making a react native app that loads data from google firebase and then display it on a page, when a user clicks on any of the products aa modal will open to show more datails.

I am using useEffect to load the data on page load then display then results:

```
 const fetchData = async () => {
    const categories = db.collection("productsDB");
    const collections = await categories
      .limit(6)
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        const items = [];

        querySnapshot.forEach((documentSnapshot) => {
          items.push({
            ...documentSnapshot.data(),
            key: documentSnapshot.id,
          });
        });

        setItems(items);
        setLoading(false);
      });

    return () => collections();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

and the show them like this:

```
{loading ? (
              <ActivityIndicator />
            ) : (
              items.map((item) => (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.queryResult}
                  key={item.key}
                  onPress={() => {
                    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
                  }}
                >
                  <View style={styles.queryResultContent}>
                    <Image
                      style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
                      source={{ uri: String(item.images) }}
                    />

                    <View>
                      <Text style={styles.queryInfoHeader}>{item.name}</Text>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                  <View>
                    <ProductModal
                      isModalVisible={modalVisible}
                      setModalVisible={setModalVisible}
                      navigation={navigation}
                      {...item}
                    />
                  </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              ))
            )}
```

when I open the modal, it opens the modal for all of the products and doesnt really matter if I click on the first product or what, it opens all of the modals, and I am not sure how to get rid of this!

is there any better way to write this function?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same `modalVisible` flag for all of your modals; therefore, they either are all visible or all hidden.

Why not have a single modal rather than rendering a bunch of them in the loop, and pass the item as a prop to it?

Comment: this was the idea actually, there is only one modal but the flag is the same for all the elemens therefore, when I click on one of them it opens all of them, but  its just one modal component that I calling like u said and I am trying to pass the item as a prop to it.

Comment: Right now, you do have `n` modals because they are rendering in the loop